# stdout and stderr entangled?

Tags: c, stdout

I am writing a function mimicking printf.

```
int prf(char *string,...){
char out_char;
int out_int;
char *out_string;
char intstr[30];
va_list argp;
va_start(argp,string);
for(int i=0;*string != '\0';i++){
    if(*string != '%'){
        fwrite(string,1,1,stdout);
    }

    else{

    switch(*++string){
            case 'c':
            out_char =va_arg(argp,int);
            fwrite(&out_char,1,1,stdout);
            debug("WOW");
            break;
            case 'd':
            out_int = va_arg(argp,int);
            snprintf(intstr,30,"%d",out_int);
            prstring(&intstr,stdout);
            break;
            case 's':
            out_string =va_arg(argp,char *);
            int j =0;
            while(out_string[j] !='\0'){
                fwrite(&out_string[j],1,1,stdout);
                j++;
            }
            break;
            default:
            sentinel("this shouldnt appear");
        }
    }
    string++;
}
va_end(argp);
return 0;
error:
va_end(argp);
return -1;
```

And i placed a debug function which is defined here:

```
#define debug(M,...) fprintf(stderr,"DEBUG: (%s :%d :%s) " M "\n",__FILE__,__LINE__,__FUNCTION__,##__VA_ARGS__)
```

when i used the function :

```
prf("1235 %d 1123 %c",12,'1');
```

The program return this

```
DEBUG: (1235 12 1123 1E:\gay\ex25_1.c :31 :prf) WOW
```

Except the debugging prints, everything else worked normally.
As far as i know, stdout and stderr are printed out separately.
Then what may have caused this entanglement?

Comment: Where do you want stdout and stderr to go? If you want them to both go to the same place, then this is basically inevitable.

Comment: What happens when you run your test program like this (assuming Unix shell): `./test_program >stdout 2>stderr`? What's in the file `stdout` afterwards? What's in the file `stderr`? Since both `stdout` and `stderr` are written to the terminal, it could be confuning. A lot depends on what's in the rest of the test harness. What you've shown isn't an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve))
(or MRE or whatever name SO now uses; MCVE was good for over five years and it did not need changing). For example, do you use `setvbuf()` or `setbuf()` anywhere?

Comment: This *is* strange behaviour.

Comment: Well, i did it on terminal and it's working normally.

Comment: Somehow Sublime Text got it mixed up.

Comment: `stdout`, by default, is line buffered; `stderr`, by default, is not buffered. Try `fflush(stdout);` after every write to `stdout`